# Detecting changes to a SQL view

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have several underlying data tables and some SQL views that apply business logic to those tables. I have a process that at every 5min interval will check the view to see if anything has changed from the last 5min check. I was wondering the best way to implement this step. Initial thoughts is using a check_sum/hashbytes on the view and then if not equal, doing some type of row by row comparison on primary keys but that doesn't seem too efficient. Is there a better way to identify which rows have been changed (or deleted) in the view?

I want to shy away from using triggers on the underlying tables due to some business requirements. Any thoughts?

Comment: It will perform a heck of a lot better if you can flag the row as `changed` at the time you change it rather than comparing data later.

Comment: Otherwise, regardless of being a view (its the same principle at a table) you have to compare the data now with a snapshot from 5 mins ago. That sounds painful... the check_sum idea is just going to add computational overhead, so unlikely to gain much over a regular compare each column of interest.

Comment: What will you do if the data has changed? Why the aversion to triggers?

Comment: One way to do it, is to have a separate audit log table where you can record individual changes such as table name, column name, PK, value of each change and date and time. You can then read this table at 5 min intervals to figure out what has changed. This can be implemented without triggers, but the standard way is to use triggers.

Comment: Sounds like a job suited for Temporal tables, if you're using SQL Server 2016 or newer

Answer (score 1):

The closest you will get to what you want is Query Notifications < https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/query-notifications-in-sql-server >